# DMN rule for checking reference data

Tags: validation, rules, dmn

New to dmn rule and trying to evaluate a condition.

Suppose I have 2 input tables.
Input A has keys - keyA1, keyA2
Input B has keys - keyB1, keyB2

I want to find out if each row in Input A has corresponding row in Input B based on keys.

Can it be achieved via DMN rule engine?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Input A` is a (DMN) Relation with column `keys` with the example entries you provided,
Assuming `Input B` is another Relation with column `keys` with the example entries you provided, you want to check each element of `Input A.keys` is contained in the `Input B.keys`.

You can achieve it with the following expression:

```
all( for aKey in Input A.keys return list contains( Input B.keys, aKey ) )
```

refs:

- [all()](https://kiegroup.github.io/dmn-feel-handbook/#all-list)
- [list contains()](https://kiegroup.github.io/dmn-feel-handbook/#list-contains-list-element)

Comment: Thanks...Sorry for not being very clear with my question. keyA1 and keyA2 are separate columns in input table A and the same for input B. Can the above expression still be used to evaluate group of keys together?